# User's address/location to autofill in address entry field

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, geolocation, location

Before,I want my output that it will autofill/complete the user's location/address in her/his address entry field, Assume user will tap the address entry field then his/her location will fill up. I tried to search in the internet about that thing but sadly, I cant find a solution.
So I came up to a idea that, inside my address entry field I will put a image button then if user click it, it will open the map. Below is the code of my Runtest.xaml.cs[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhWih.png)

`

```
  async public void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MapPage());
        }
```

`

What I expect to happen is upon clicking the icon inside the address entry field, It will open and map( I achieve it) but it must zoom to user's location like real time map? then after that user will see his/her location and maybe he/she can pin it, then the address will move or let say write into the address field. Anyone can help me ? Im new currently working our thesis, and Im newbie to xamarin cross platform.
Any idea or links that are related to my problems, is highly appreciated :)
No javascript pls but if your solution will include js then maybe I will to read it as I can.

Thank you.

Comment: You asked this same question last week.  Please do not post duplicates.  If you want to find the user's current location/address, you can do that with Geolocation and Reverse Geocoding.  See [Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/)

Comment: @Jason Yes sir,I asked last week but my post was deleted so I ask again. And thank you for the link you posted. I will explore  it.

Comment: I made the same suggestion in your previous post.

Comment: @jason sir, I already make some code in getting my location, latlong and even placemark, but I done this by setting a location point in my emulator. May I ask if there's a way that I can get my location without setting my emulator's location settings?

Comment: The emulator defaults to a fixed location.  You need to test on a real device if you need true GPS functionality

Comment: @jason- aaah ok sir, but if you say test on real device, Do I need to change my code in getting the latlong or it is the same just how I get my location using the emulator?

Comment: no, the code is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jason suggested, you can retrieve the device's current `Latitude` and `Longitude` by using [Xamarin.Essentials: Geolocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?tabs=android) and then [use Reverse Geocoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geocoding?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android#using-reverse-geocoding) to get the **address** based on the current `Latitude` and `Longitude`.

Here are some video links below that you can refer to it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android#related-video

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geocoding?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android#related-video

Comment: may, sir I already explore and play some code in the internet, like what you've mention, the latlong. However when I clicked btncurrentlocation, it gives wrong latlong, in the map it will appear at google address(somewhere at california) and in fact my location is in PH. Anyway, Thanks for the link sir.

Comment: Yes sir, I already put that in my androidmanifest.xml.
Yes sir, I accept your answer because it is help me a lot.